# Add AD FS authentication for existing project

Tags: visual-studio, adfs

I have project, which should use AD FS authentication.
When we create new solution, we can click to "Change Authentication button", but how to make the same for existing solution and project?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the button links in the OWIN OpenID Connect stack.

Some [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development).

Or you could add WIF - like this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation) (it's for Azure AD but the principles are the same).